# Which metric should be used for benchmarks?

Tags: language-agnostic, benchmarking

When I'm benchmarking some code, either on a fixed set of input data, or on random input where the randomness doesn't affect the control flow: what is the best metric to use to assess the performance of my code?

I've always used minimum runtime over multiple runs because any deviation from the minimum will be due to the CPU being busy with unrelated things, but I couldn't find any reliable sources confirming that that's the best practice. Other obvious choices are average or median run time. (Maximum seems odd, as it will probably be dominated by unrelated CPU spikes.) Are there any better ways to make sense of the statistical data gathered from several runs?

As paxdiablo points out, if I can measure CPU time directly that would be ideal. But what do I do when I can only benchmark wall time?

As I said I was unable to find anything reliable on this, but maybe I just didn't find the right Google keywords, so if you can point me to anything existing, that would already be a great help. Also, please feel free to migrate this to Programmers.SE, if this question is too general for SO.

Comment: The best metric is whatever you want to measure. What is performance to the users of your program?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd What sparked this question was actually [a challenge over on PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35202/number-crunching-benchmark), but I've been using the same technique in other cases. Mostly high-performance libraries for involved scientific computations. I suppose if someone wants to make the most use of it, they will try to run it on a dedicated machine, but wall time is definitely what matters to them.

Answer (score 3):

If you're benchmarking CPU time, some systems will provide you CPU usage independent of elapsed, or wall, time.

You're right that wall time can vary depending on what the system may be doing but this generally doesn't affect CPU time.

By way of example, the `time` utility in Linux (and other UNIX-like operating system) report as follows:

```
pax> time sleep 1

real    0m1.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

The real time is wall time, a touch over a second. The `user` and `sys` time are time spent using the CPU, which is minimal in this case because the process is waiting for the sleep to finish (an action that takes practically no CPU time).

If you have this facility available, that's the one you should use.

If you *don't* have a facility like that, then you'll probably have to use statistical methods, such as minimising CPU usage by other processes and running you own process hundreds of times to form a decent picture.

Whether you take the average or minimum (or something weird like the average after removing outliers) will depend on whatever school of statistics you follow. You should opt for the minimum if, as you say, you're *sure* any variation is not due to the workload itself.

And ensuring other loads are minimised is important. If you have a rogue process taking up 97% of the CPU grunt, the minimum will be vastly skewed upwards in comparison to a mostly-idle system (that's why CPU time is so much better than wall time).

Comment: Yes, that's an option. But say, all I have available *is* wall time (because I'm benchmarking something from within the code and only have access to elapsed time). I'll edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: Using CPU time is not a bad idea, but it doesn't exactly eliminate all the sources of variation and the underlying question of which summary statistic to use. In fact CPU time is really just the sum of wall clock time while the thread(s) of the process are running, so the main problem it avoids is including time while your process is switched out. OTOH querying the CPU time is itself an expensive call so it can introduce noise itself.

Answer (score 2):

> I've always used minimum runtime over multiple runs because any deviation from the minimum will be due to the CPU being busy with unrelated things, but I couldn't find any reliable sources confirming that that's the best practice. Other obvious choices are average or median run time. (Maximum seems odd, as it will probably be dominated by unrelated CPU spikes.) Are there any better ways to make sense of the statistical data gathered from several runs?

[Chen, J. and Revels, J., 2016. Robust benchmarking in noisy environments. arXiv preprint arXiv:1608.04295.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04295) has some moderately extensive and mathematically justified arguments about how to do robust benchmarking.
The simple version is: use minimum.

As you expect because it boils down to:
*noise can only ever make things run slower, never faster.*
as such `minimum` not `mean` or `median` is the best estimator of the true time.
Since the model is `true_time + noise` where `noise` is nonnegative, and thus the sample that is smallest must have the smallest error (since `true_time` doessn't chane between samples, only noise).

Answer (score 2):

Usually min and median should be pretty similar, unless it's very noisy.  If you assume other load is actually noisy and not constant, and your benchmark isn't so long that it averages away the variation, then checking for that can be a good way to tell that the system isn't too noisy for benchmarking.

Occasionally (especially for micro-benchmarks) you'll find a low outlier even on a mostly-idle system. I usually ignore that and **take the lowest number in the cluster of repeatable results** if I'm doing a couple test-runs by hand.  If the system is pretty noisy, the median might not be in the lowest cluster, but there hopefully *is* a cluster of fast results that are somewhat similar.  That's what you want; as Lyndon pointed out, noise (other load, interrupts, cache pollution) will only make things slower.

(Although I think such low outliers are usually real, like some happy coincidence of alignments of things to avoid branch aliasing, or hugepages lined up well, or IDK what.  Maybe even some meta-stable equilibrium of CPU instruction scheduling that can be disturbed and fall down to a lower-throughput state. Again, this is for a non-repeatable good performance on a mostly-idle system.)

---

**OTOH, depending on what you're benchmarking, this might not make sense.**  If the real-world conditions for your code running will involve competition for memory bandwidth and cache, and/or for I/O, code that has a worse "best case" but suffers less from the noise can be better overall.

e.g. you might have a really fast algorithm that really depends on having 20MiB of stuff hot in cache.  If other threads on other cores are usually going to be "polluting" cache (including from other VMs on the same hardware in a cloud host), that's not actually the best choice even if it occasionally runs really fast.

Code that uses more CPU cycles in the best case (e.g. by compressing or recomputing data, instead of a giant lookup table or uncompressed cache) might be best in average real-world conditions.

Or code that uses multiple threads or something to decouple / pipeline some processing steps might have more overhead and be slower in the best case, but more resilient to noise and better in the average case.

Be careful about tuning for the benchmark instead of real system conditions, if things might be different.  **And in general try to write code that doesn't over-consume shared resources like memory bandwidth**; e.g. for number-crunching over big arrays, cache-block by doing multiple steps on a block that fits in the L2 cache of a single core, so you're not re-reading from shared L3 or main memory in every pass over your whole data set.